# How to sleep a pod in Kubernetes

Tags: linux, docker, kubernetes, containers

I'm starting using Kubernetes/Docker and would like to know how to configure it for sleep some pod (container) after 30 minutes of inactivity.

My team will working with a lot of pod and some of them will have to sleep after some time without user access.

[Heroku free Dyno](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/free-dyno-hours) have as well this feature.

So, how to configure Kubernetes or Docker to be able do this feature? Anyone can help?

Comment: You can have haproxy installed and use haproxy stats to monitor the activities of pod

Comment: Answer on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34276570/kubernetes-pod-with-sleep-command-hangs?noredirect=1&lq=1) might be useful.

Comment: @Faizan that thread is about running the `sleep` command in a pod, not putting a pod to sleep

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes supports pod autoscaling based on CPU usage. Something like:

```
kubectl autoscale deployment/my-deployment --min=1 --max=15 --cpu-percent=80
```

Check the full documentation here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale-walkthrough/
It also provides examples for metrics other than CPU usage.